# Logged In user still has an empty session symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I have trouble displaying user username after login with Symfony 5 and I've figured out that the session object is still null after the user logged in this is my AuthAuthenticator.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class AuthAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements
    PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator,
        CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager,
        UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
    ) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'app_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route') &&
            $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'matricule' => $request->request->get('matricule'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token')
        ];
        $request
            ->getSession()
            ->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $credentials['matricule']);

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager
            ->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy(['matricule' => $credentials['matricule']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException(
                'The Member Matricule could not be found.'
            );
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid(
            $user,
            $credentials['password']
        );
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(
        Request $request,
        TokenInterface $token,
        $providerKey
    ) {
        if (
            $targetPath = $this->getTargetPath(
                $request->getSession(),
                $providerKey
            )
        ) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('home'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login');
    }
}
```

an this is the security.yml file

```
security:
  encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: auto

  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
  providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: matricule
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      anonymous: lazy
      guard:
        authenticators:
          - App\Security\AuthAuthenticator
      logout:
        path: app_logout
        # where to redirect after logout
        # target: app_any_route

      # activate different ways to authenticate
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
      # switch_user: true

  # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
  # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
    ROLE_GESTIONNAIRE: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_GESTIONNAIRE] }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/publication, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/publication/new, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/comment, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

this is a part of the redirect page on success

```
      <div id="main">
        <div class="inner">
          <!-- Header -->
          <header id="header">
            <a href="{{ path('home') }}" class="logo">
              <strong>
                {% block pagename %}

                {% endblock %}
              </strong> COMSAS
            </a>
            <ul class="icons">
              {% if app.user %}
                <li><a href="#">{{ app.user.username }}</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/logout">Deconnexion</a>
                </li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              {% else %}
                <li>
                  <a href="{{ path('app_login') }}" class="icon fas fa-user">
                    <span class="label">Login</span>
                  </a>
                </li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              {% endif %}
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="icon brands fa-twitter">
                  <span class="label">Twitter</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="icon brands fa-facebook-f">
                  <span class="label">Facebook</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="{{ path('publication_index') }}"
                  class="icon fas fa-comments">
                  <span class="label">Forum</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </header>
          {% block body %}

          {% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="inner">
          <!-- Search -->
          <section id="search" class="alt">
            <form method="post" action="#">
              <input type="text" name="query" id="query" placeholder="Search" />
            </form>
          </section>

          <!-- Menu -->
          <nav id="menu">
            <header class="major">
              <h2>
                Menu
              </h2>
            </header>
            <ul>
              {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                <li><a href="{{ path('admin_home') }}">Espace Admin</a></li>
              {% elseif is_granted('ROLE_GESTIONNAIRE') %}
                <li><a href="{{ path('admin_home') }}">Gestionnaire</a></li>
              {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ path('publication_index') }}">Forum</a></li>
              {% endif %}
              <li><a href="{{ path('home') }}">Homepage</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{ path('generic') }}">Generic</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{ path('elements') }}">Elements</a></li>
```

I need your help because i don't understand why the session is still empty even if the authentication is successfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue resides in your access_control configuration.

The way access_control works, is that it will stop on the first line that matches the path, beginning from the top of the ACL.

What happens, in your case, is that the route doesn't match ^/admin, so it goes to the second line and matches with ^/ and therefore consider the user to be an anonymous user.

I see two changes neccessary to fix this:

First, move your your base path ACL to the last position because it is the least restrictive, every url will match.

This one

```
- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Second, when the ACL role is IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, it will load an anonymous token in your user session therefore, not your expected user.

The final result for the access_control would be:

```
access_control:
- { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_GESTIONNAIRE] }    
- { path: ^/publication, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/publication/new, roles: ROLE_USER }
- { path: ^/comment, roles: ROLE_USER }
- { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**Edit:**
Okay, I just realized you're trying to have your homepage "^/" be anonymous as well as authenticated.

You need to have [ROLE_USER , IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY ] as well at the bottom of your ACL.

Now with the latest changes you made, It might be that you're being redirected to the login after logging in.

If you look inside your **FormLoginAuthenticator** at the method **onAuthenticationSuccess()**

There is a redirect with the $targetPath which takes precedence over the homepage.

```
//If $targetPAth == "/login", you're redirected to login, therefore an anonymous token.
if ( $targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(),$providerKey) )
{
    return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
}
```

It might be that the $targetPath is "/login" which IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY in your ACL. Consequently, by entering  the route "/login" after logging in puts an anonymous token in session.

If this doesn't work, Sharing your login form twig template as well as your routes and their URL would help a lot.

Comment: I have this error when i'm trying to test your solution `There is no extension able to load the configuration for "access_control" (in /home/redwolf/Labs/Php/Symfony/gestion-COMSAS/config/packages/security.yaml). Looked for namespace "access_control", found "framework", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "sensio_framework_extra", "twig", "maker", "monolog", "security", "doctrine_fixtures" in /home/redwolf/Labs/Php/Symfony/gestion-COMSAS/config/packages/security.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/home/redwolf/Labs/Php/Symfony/gestion-COMSAS/config/packages/security.yaml").`

Comment: @Nelson Use a Yaml validator on your security.yml. My answer contains invalid spacing for yaml files which are very strict. http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: I suggest to avoid copy pasting in a yaml file and make the change manually by typing. I wasted 3 hours the other day. I had copy/pasted into my security.yml. Got the same error you just commented. The two files looked the same, but when I discarded my changes and typed it anew. It finally worked. Beware of those Yaml validator.

Comment: `Checking support on guard authenticator. authenticator="App\\Security\\AuthAuthenticator"
Jan 30 00:35:00 |DEBUG| SECURI Guard authenticator does not support the request. 
Jan 30 00:35:00 |INFO | SECURI Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token`. That the output of server log